# How do we judge if an action is moral or not if there are competing frameworks by which we judge them?

Tags: ethics

If the same action can be moral and immoral in different ethical frameworks (e.g. consequentialism, virtue ethics), how can we judge if the action is moral or not? Is morality ultimately subjective depending on the framwork we are using? Does it ultimately come down to the question of adopting the most suitable ethical framework in different contexts? What justfies the framework's "suitability" then?

Comment: If "moral judgments" are depending on "ethical frameworks", maybe there is no super-ethical point of view in order to compare frameworks...

Comment: We adopt *our own* moral framework and then judge according to it. And we do not shift it from context to context as convenience or "suitability" dictate, that would not be "adopting". Of course, we may use other frameworks (e.g. the person's own, when judging them, or the one prevailing in society, as we understand it) when judging, but such judgements are conditional. They provide not what is simply moral, but only what is moral-according-to to be used in further deliberations.

Comment: If a moral theory can be morally correct & morally wrong at the same time in some framework, then why have it in the first place?  What value would it serve in reality.  Why people keep thinking ethics is morality is generally caused by people confusing Psychology with Philosophy. Some really don’t see the difference.  Question like the OP show many people see no difference.  Ethics is not based on objective truth whereas Morality decisions ARE.  Morality is universal, & applies to all people on Earth.  Ethical theories are more on how some people can benefit from the act — not all but some.

Comment: @Logikal I meant a moral action can be wrong and right in different "frameworks" (Theories). Could you provide a definition of Ethics and Morality? I don't quite get your last point.

Comment: Indeed any philosophical question related to words such as "beneficial", "right", "good" is very tough. Even the grandly conceived and named intellectual *theory of everything* has no iota of steps to frame and quantify what's good or bad, beneficial or harmful, yet everyone has their own criterion without any difficulty. I call it *paradox of morality*, and Hume called it *is-ought problem*...

Comment: No moral concepts proper should not have counter examples. You are thinking ethics is interchangeable with morals. The last comment I made distinguished them. Ethics is local whereas morality is universal for all human beings. Ethical theories are not always for all human beings be particular people in an area. Ethics also is more authority driven where morality is not. Why even honor an ethical theory if it is not covering 100 percent of humans everywhere? Why would we need that? I await your answer to that question  specifically. Seems to make no sense to do if the theory works 2 days a week

Comment: @Logikal I mean you plaster that ideology all over the place, but what is the point of a universal, objective morality if you can't define it? Can you even prove that it theoretically exists?

Comment: @hoaxer, what are you talking about? You don't understand the idea of a proposition being true universally? Are women human beings everywhere on Earth or is that subjective to you? What are you talking about when you say I cannot even define it? You know what universally true means aka objective truth don't you? Seems to me you are confusing ethics with morality.

Comment: If people find out about what you did, and nobody cares, the action is moral. If they do care, it's immoral.

Comment: In other words, behavior (moral or immoral) happens within the framework of a community. It is the community's opinion which matters.. that is true in every circumstance.

Comment: @CanadianCoder Perhaps a community should decide its opinions in advance?

Comment: @ScottRowe that's generally how it works, but in practice people don't get together and map out ethical frameworks based on some kind of philosophical logic / axiom. That's just not how people function in the real world

Comment: @CanadianCoder Maybe they should? If you were starting off to build something and you didn't plan, then 99 times out of 100 it will go badly. Well, 99 times later, maybe we all should read the memo?

Answer (score 2):

Our moral judgements do not depend entirely on an explicitly held moral frameworks. In philosophy, a moral theory is put forward as an attempt to systematize and make more principled our pre-reflective moral judgements. That isn't to say that pre-reflective moral judgements are entirely concept-independent. Everybody is raised in a culture where they learn various moral concepts that influence their moral judgements. However, it is also true that there are many examples of people having intuitive moral judgements that contradict the culturally prevalent norms and attitudes. Thus, it seems to be a background assumption of normative moral philosophy that our moral judgements function like concept-laden perceptions. Our moral concepts influence but do not determine our moral judgements. This premise justifies the common method of argument in philosophical moral argument which is to consider judgements about various concrete moral situations and evaluate the predictions of different theories in the light of those judgements.

Comment: Right, concepts never determine anything, they are always explanations after the fact.

Comment: I would say that in an ideal philosophical inquiry, concepts are in reciprocal dialogue with direct experience. If we let concepts be determinative, we get ideology, if we let experience be determinative we get some species of irrationalism. The magic of moral philosophy done well is that it remains responsive to both the raw intuition of our concrete human experience and the rigor of rational thought and the power of effective abstraction.

Comment: It would be a good start if we could somehow just get people to have the right "pre-reflective moral judgements".

Comment: There is an epistemic issue here. We can't stand outside of our practices of moral judgement and reasoning in order to somehow select the "right" ones independent of our own tacit moral commitments.  There is a starting presupposition (or methodological axiom if you prefer) needed to ground the truth-finding of modern moral theory. Roughly that reciprocal revision of moral judgements and moral theories in light of each other in a process of good faith rational inquiry will tend towards improving the correctness of both. Call this methodological axiom Reciprocal Revision.

Comment: I suspect that the reason why so many people's moral beliefs appear not to be responsive to change in light of philosophical dialogue is that many people are not committed tacitly or otherwise to Reciprocal Revision (RR) as a principle of moral belief formation. It is a rather special fact that most moral philosophers tacitly accept this principle (I would argue that even many philosophers who would deny RR explicitly nevertheless tacitly employ it in their argumentative practices, e.g., Peter Singer, etc.). So an interesting question then becomes: what leads a person to accept or reject RR?

Comment: RR sounds like Hofstadter's "renormalized rationality". It seems too obvious to reject, and too basic to avoid. What is it called in math where you hone in on the point you are seeking by running the equation repeatedly with the previous result? Is there some better way to get the answer? I don't see any place for a debate.

Answer (score 2):

You'd theoretically have some rough guidelines in terms of what all people agree upon is "good" and "bad". Like idk being deprived of agency, being harmed, ostracized, conflict, violence, destruction, etc. would all be things most people would argue are not good.

So if your moral framework end up with that, you should probably ditch it even if your philosophical logic appears to be good to you, because it's practically not working.

Though unfortunately things aren't that easy all the time, because while probably most people think these things are bad, almost hinting at a universal morality, far less people don't have a problem using them as retribution, punishment, deterrence or whatnot, for wrong doing against their moral framework.
So that in the worst case it's bad only if the other person does it.

Now moral frameworks try to answer the question of what is ultimately good and bad and people try to derive some ethics from it (a guideline on how you should act moral). But in practical terms they only really concern themselves with one moral framework at a time. That makes it much easier to judge because there is no conflict of moral frameworks. But the problem is that most of these moral frameworks kinda have a point, so unless they are garbage to begin with, you will encounter edge cases where your morality tells you to act in a certain way, but where this will lead to problems. Not with your self-encapsulated moral framework, but with reality. Like if you're arguing that the other person is acting "wrong", but they have no conceivable alternative to doing what they are doing.

Then it's still possible to pass judgement, but it's kinda pointless beyond self-affirmation. Because it's not going to be any productive in solving the underlying problem.

So yeah in reality we more or less arbitrarily pick one framework and judge by that one. Like either a powerful person or group decides that (tyranny, monarchy, theocracy, aristocracy, ...) or the ethical framework is less of a coherent moral framework but more of an agreement on a list of dos and don'ts. Which might be influenced and guided by one or more moral frameworks but which don't have to adhere to one in particular (unless explicitly chosen). So that ethics is just "follow the laws" and that fits into subjective morality because the individuals got their part in shaping the makeup of these laws. (at least in theory).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, while religions typically assert that any action can be definitely immoral, in philosophy actions can only be immoral with respect to a chosen framework. Philosophy recognizes multiple different viable ethical frameworks, and so choices may occur where the frameworks disagree.

In such cases the decider has to choose a framework to follow.

This however is not much different from having just a single framework, even in that situation the interpretation and application of the framework to a specific situation can be subjective. So a decider would still have to make a choice of choosing a certain interpretation and application even if there were just one framework.

So the responsibility of the decider remains with the decider, and the decider needs to consider in general how to justify their choice.

In a society, a decider that chooses a very different (and not generally accepted) ethical framework than most other people may become regarded as acting immorally, in particular if seen as having cherry-picked a special framework just for one action to justify it.

Societies however may tolerate people deciding based on frameworks that only minorities follow, as long as those minorities don't make up rules as they go.

As an example (speaking loosely here for illustration), in many some countries young men are expected to perform military service (moth morally and legally, or just one of the two) but may be exempt from it if it's against their religion (both legally and morally). On the other hand some religious minorities might have rules about female circumcision or honor killings which would not be tolerable within other societies (legally or ethically).

So the choice in frameworks is not arbitrary, and philosophic rigour requires a lot of justification and consistency to consider some system as an ethical framework.

I believe there is no objective guidance on how to choose the right framework for each situation, it seems to me most "guides" recommend to apply multiple framework when in doubt, and combine the results in reasonable ways (trying to satisfy them all as much as possible). When no compromise is possible and multiple alternatives equally good/bad, then a decider appears to have freedom to pick any of the best alternatives.

Comment: Take the best of all the frameworks and mash them together? It worked for Civilization.

Answer (score 0):

Morality is based on personal beliefs of right and wrong and a judgement is an opinion based on these beliefs. Ethics reflect the acceptable beliefs of a group of individuals whose personal morals may not always align with the group but accept group decision.

Based on these definitions, any individual may make a moral judgement on an action regardless of the ethical framework. This judgement, however, will never supercede the ethics of the group.
So a lawyers morality will be secondary to the code of ethics of the profession.

Comment: "*One man with courage makes a majority.*" - Andrew Jackson

Answer (score 0):

On a practical level, a man or a woman does not tend to subscribe to competing frameworks of ethics. Hence they can judge a moral claim. Likewise a community and a society, despite being a community of individuals, likewise and largely subscribe to the same framework of ethics, and this is why a society or community can also judge moral claims. It is one reason why we call them a community or society as opposed to a set of alienated and atomised individuals.

What you are asking about is the theoretical ground of moral claims. Well, despite there being many local variations and modalities, moral frameworks are not incommensurable. All ethical frameworks say that murder is wrong, for example. This is one reason for believing in moral realism.

Comment: "All ethical frameworks say that murder is wrong, for example." Sure about that? There seem to be quite a few who would weasel around by not calling it murder if officials (soldiers, police) do it or if it's part of a ritual sacrifice or whatnot.

Comment: @haxor789 But, if they said that, they would be wrong. It seems like we are searching everywhere for the ground under our feet. It's just obvious, and some people are just wrong.

Comment: Is it that obvious? I mean an obvious moral would imply some sort of ethics (how you should act) but for every possible ethic you could probably find a series of pathological examples where it's either unclear or where you'd have to make exceptions to it and not just one but many.

Comment: @haxor789 so filter out the pathological examples. Make the exceptions that are justified by the circumstances.

Comment: But at that point it's already far from "obvious" and the ability to readily cast an action as wrong.

Comment: @haxor789: There is no legal code or moral code that has had the assent of people over an extended period of time that has declared murder to be lawful. Otherwise sanctioned acts of killing are named as other categories because they are seen as apart from this. This includes killings in the line of duty by police or soldiers in battle or ritual sacrifice as say by the Aztecs. We do not call it murder. Those that do have an issue with the underlying rationale. You might think this is being "weasel" with words but it is not.

Answer (score 0):

> If the same action can be moral and immoral in different ethical frameworks (e.g. consequentialism, virtue ethics), how can we judge if the action is moral or not?

A person will either be sufficiently persuaded by a framework (and/or by the solution to which the framework leads), or they will remain undecided and fall into a moral dilemma/trilemma (etc) as a result of being unable to resolve which framework is best.

If your moral framework is a strict religious one, you might deem that a god's morality outweighs all others, regardless of how complete or consistent that morality is in comparison to others.

But do we ever choose the things which persuade us? Or do they choose us? It is plausible that we almost never choose our beliefs; that we are either persuaded of a proposition or we are not. Persuasion seems exerted upon us via experience rather than choice, in which case the answer to the question of 'how we judge if the action is moral or not' might simply be:

'By comparing the assumptions, methodology and/or conclusions of the framework to our existing beliefs'. Whichever fits best wins out.

Even if a framework is capable of *changing* our beliefs, we again find ourselves in the position of being unavoidably persuaded, as opposed to some being in some state of choosing what to be persuaded by.

Comment: You can choose which alternative you like, but you can't decide which alternatives there will be, or what you will like or dislike about them. You can certainly be skeptical of your likes and dislikes, which is what I would suggest. Know why you want to choose something, otherwise you are just lost.